# Promise all with a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to use `Promise.all()` but creating an array of promises is calling all my promises. (using axios)

```
export function myPromise(a, b, data){
    return my.patch(`/some/${a}/path/${b}`, data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
 }
```

Then I try to create an array here:

```
 let otherVal = 12
 let group = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
 let data = {
                // somedata
            }
 let promises = group.map(item => {
            return saveMapping(otherVal, item.id, data);
        })

 Promise.all(promises)
```

before it even gets to promise all, it starts the promises, so obviously I'm calling the function as I map it. How do I add it to the array as a reference?

Comment: Clearly you've simplified the code here because there's no practical difference between your code and the code in the answer by @torazaburo

Comment: Of course calling the function does execute `my.patch` to create the promise, which is totally fine - `Promise.all` takes an array of *promises* to await, not an array of functions or "references" (whatever that means). What is your problem?

Comment: Sounds like its expected functionality then, if the when I map the group calls the promises, then `Promise.all()` simply reports back on behalf of ALL the promises referenced in the array, correct?

Comment: I was under the impression that promise all calls the promises referenced in its arguments I guess.

Comment: @Philll_t promises are not called, functions are. Promises are just objects representing asynchronous results - they are function return values typically.

Comment: apparently axios has its own `all` https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store functions in your array, then invoke them at the time of `Promise.all`:

```
let promiseFuncs = group.map(item => () => saveMapping(otherVal, item.id, data));

Promise.all(promiseFuncs.map(f => f()));
```

Comment: Nah, that wouldn't make any difference except for being more complicated.

Comment: I believe the point is that he is doing the `Proimse.all` in a different place than where he is preparing the promises. He wants to create a list of promises in one place, then pass it somewhere where it will be invoked. Otherwise his question wouldn't make any sense,